# BigQuery - default expiration time

Tags: google-bigquery

How to update the default expiration time for a dataset to never.

Here is an example how it is set to 60 days,
but I would like the dataset to never expired.

ALTER SCHEMA mydataset
SET OPTIONS(default_table_expiration_days=60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
ALTER SCHEMA mydataset SET OPTIONS(default_table_expiration_days=null);
```

It will actually set expiration to never and remove that option from the dataset schema information.